# swift 3 pass data from a tableView to another TableVIew?

Tags: swift

I populated a tableView with an array of dictionaries Now How can I  save  the cell contents  to Core Data and retrieve it in another tableView ?

I loaded an array of dictionaries to a tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SourceTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = sourceFeeds[indexPath.row]["title"]
    cell.linkLabel.text = sourceFeeds[indexPath.row]["link"]


    return cell

}
```

Now I want to save those link and title to core data in cell selection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SourceTableViewCell


    if self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none {

        self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark



    } else {


        self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none



    }


}
```

I want to mention that  "sourceFeeds" array has loaded from plist!

Comment: This is very broad. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: It's very, very inefficient to call `tableView.cellForRow(at` three times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem finally!